# Is this correct way to estimate bootstrap SD?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(1)
norm = rnorm(10000000, 10, 50) # "population" which is unknown

norm1 = sample(norm, 1000, replace = FALSE) # Random sample

norm2 = replicate(10000, {      
  x = sample(norm1, 1000, replace = TRUE)      
  sd(x)      
})

mean(norm2)
```

Returns a mean SD of 49.91. I thought that the bootstrap would return a closer estimate to the population than the sample. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated the sd of the samples (which is 50) and not the bootstrap sd.

```
set.seed(1)
norm <- rnorm(10000000, 10, 50)                # population which is unknown

# This line is not needed
# norm1 = sample(norm, 1000, replace = FALSE)  # Random sample

norm2 <- replicate(10000, {      
  x <- sample(norm, 1000, replace = TRUE)      # Take a sample of norm (not of norm1)
  x                                            # Don't calculate the sd here
})

# Calculate the mean of each sample
sample_means <- apply(norm2, 2, mean)

# Calculate the sd of the sample means
sd(sample_means)
```

Comment: Which results in a SD of 1.59. I expected it to be closer to 50, which is the population SD. I thought the idea with bootstrap was to get an estimate of the population.

Comment: Also, if I skip norm1, I´m sampling from the "population", which is unknown. That was the reason why I first took a sample.

Comment: @Jixxi; bootstrapping assumes that your sample (norm1) is the population , as in practice you will not know the unknown population(norm). So check `mean(norm1)` - should be close to `mean(norm2)`. However, this just checks bias in the bootstrapping procedure. The BS really is more often used to generate , for example, a confidence interval for your statistic (in this case sd). (To examine this the way you are you would need to resample norm1, (due to sampling variation in the draws of norm1, but then this is why we are calculating a confidence interval by bootstrapping.)